# How To Disable Category Hierarchy In Categories Widget?

Tags: categories, widgets

I want to disable all category's hierarchy in default categories widget. With a code in functions.php . But how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you not want to un-tick the 'show hierarchy' button in the widget?

Answer (score 0):

I did! Write this codes in functions.php

```
add_filter( 'widget_categories_args', 'force_widget_cat_args' );

function force_widget_cat_args($cat_args) {       

$cat_args['hierarchical'] = 0;

return $cat_args;

}
```